# c++ vector/linked list hybrid

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, linked-list, hybrid

Is there a std container in c++ that acts like a hybrid between a vector and a linked list. What I mean is a data structure that overcomes the frequent reallocation overhead of std::vector and potential excess memory allocation, instead when the structure runs out of space it adds a pointer to the next allocated fragment, and only when the number of fragments reaches a certain value, the entire structure is de-fragmented into a continuous new chunk and number of fragments is set back to 0.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `std::deque`? Does it fit your requirements?

Comment: I think `std::deque` works that way, but I'm not sure though.

Comment: @Constantinius I always thought `std::deque` was just a kind of ringbuffer and thus similar to a `std::vector` in its memory allocation behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::deque` is the closest standard container to what you describe. It is not *exactly* like this, however (for example, it pretty much has to be an array of arrays rather than a list of arrays since the latter wouldn't permit constant-time element access).

Depending on your practical requirements, it might be close enough.

Comment: So I can basically use a deque and just add the few lines of code I need to defragment it once a certain level of fragments is reached. The idea is naturally to eliminate memory hops and cache misses...

Answer (score 4):

As already said, `std::deque` comes close to your requirements. I just want to add this comparison between `std::vector` and `std::deque` which I found very helpful. [An In-Depth Study of the STL Deque Container](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/vector_vs_deque.aspx)